# Affine Maps PyTorch

Tags: neural-network

I do not understand the [following part of a tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/deep_learning_tutorial.html) (see pic below).
I am not clear about this part of code

```
lin = nn.Linear(5, 3)  # maps from R^5 to R^3, parameters A, b
# data is 2x5.  A maps from 5 to 3... can we map "data" under A?
data = autograd.Variable(torch.randn(2, 5))
print(lin(data))  # yes
```

We defined Linear layer that has 5 inputs and 3 output? and then we feed matrix of size 2x5? I do not understand what is going here...

and the idea that they want to deliver in general

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you provided is fairly simple.

The input to a `nn.Linear()`is of dimension `batch_size x feat_dim`. If you feed in `data = Variable(torch.randn(2, 5))`, you feed in a mini-batch that contains 2 data instances. Each data instance is a five-dimensional vector. For each data instance, you use the same weight matrix of your linear layer, to map their five-dimensional vector to a 3-dimensional vector. Thus your linear layer returns a matrix of dimension `2 x 3`, i.e. `batch_size x new_feat_dim`

You can feed mini-batches of any size to your linear layer.

Comment: hi, thanks for the nice explanation. But in a feed-forward network, we would not need this right? I mean I am not getting to grips with when is this needed? Is this some sort of dimensionality reduction? Or is it saying xA i.e our data 'x' multiplied by matrix A which is the weight matrix between input layer and first hidden layer

Comment: Yes, exactly. They're just spelling out what the linear layer does. The linear layer has two parameters. The weight matrix (call it A in this case) and the bias term (call it b in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)